# How to formally write a sentence in order to say that I am avaiable during a certain week for an interview

Tags: grammaire

I was supposed to have an interview this week but it was delayed. I sent them an email asking if it was delayed or still at the same date. I want to see if the grammar and the way the answer is written is polite or formal.

---

## Their Email

> Merci pour votre mail, il était en haut de ma todolist de vous appeler à ce sujet aujourd'hui.
>
> Le consultant avec lequel travaillerait le rédacteur scientifique, que FRS Consulting cherche à recruter, est absent jusqu’au 18 juillet.
>
> Donc, votre rendez-vous est décalé à la semaine du 18 juillet : avez-vous des contraintes sur cette semaine-là ? Sinon, le consultant IT concerné, xxxxx, est disponible mardi 19 toute la journée.
>
> Merci par avance pour votre réponse et désolée de ne pas vous avoir donné de nouvelles plus vite.
>
> Bien cordialement.

---

## Reply

I want to tell them that I have no constraint at all for the week of the 18th of july and that if the 19th of july is fixed I can make it.

---

> Bonjour, encore une fois,
>
> Je n'ai aucune contrainte pour la semaine du 18 juillet. Je peux prendre une journée du lundi au vendredi afin de procéder à l'entretien avec le consultant.
>
> La date du 19 Juillet me convient aussi. Je pourrais être disponible durant toute la journée.
>
> Cordialement,
>   xxxx,xxxx.

---

## Updated reply

I updated my reply. It's a compilation of the answers that were posted. The main points are be direct, assertive and right to the point.

> Bonjour xxxx,
>
> Merci pour votre réponse. Je vous remercie pour l'attention que vous
>   m'avez portée.
>
> Je suis disponible la semaine du 18 juillet.
>
> La date du 19 Juillet me convient également. Je suis disponible toute
>   la journée, que pensez vous de 10h ?
>
> Cordialement,
>
> Hani xxx.

---

Comment: Do you really write _Hello, another time,_ in english ???

Comment: I didn't want to type Re-Bonjour. and I wanted to say Hello again. I googled in french we can say "Bonjour, encore une fois"

Comment: Re-bonjour would be fine for me, although it is not used often in French. I personnally would just say Bonjour at the beginning of the message, just to stay formal. However, _Bonjour, encore une fois,_ definitely not, although I agree hello again is fine in English.

Comment: In your updated answer, you're now saying "thank you" twice (one for the answer, one for the "attention"). Sounds redundant. You should do one or the other, not both.
I'd select "Merci pour votre réponse". The other formula "Merci pour l'attention que vous portez [à ma demande]" is preferred at the end of a message where you expect some action from the reader. And I would avoid "Merci pour l'attention que vous me portez", as it could be interpreted as a personal interest.

Comment: Thank you Little Jawa I already sent it. I'll use them for the next time.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question so you don't disclose the content of the mail send by your contact ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Réponse à la question :

Dire

> "Je suis disponible (la semaine du 18 juillet)"

est plus commun et direct que la forme négative

> "Je n'ai aucune contrainte ..."

NB : Si le mail concerne quelque chose d'important, un contrat ou un entretien par exemple : préférer en français les formes affirmatives aux formes négatives.

> La date du 19 Juillet me convient aussi

Cette phrase est tout à fait correcte, mais si on souhaite relever un peu le niveau, on utilisera **également** à la place de **aussi** :

> La date du 19 Juillet me convient également

---

### Remarque annexe, mais pas des moindres :

> Bonjour, encore une fois

Cette phrase m'a un peu piqué les yeux à la première lecture : elle est correcte, mais elle sous-entend une forme d'agacement ("encore vous!") et pose plus de problèmes que le reste...
Si on veut retranscrire l'idée, plutôt dire :

> Bonjour une nouvelle fois (sans la virgule)
>   EDIT : Bonjour à nouveau

qui passera beaucoup mieux.

On peut aussi, au lieu de dire bonjour à la personne, la remercier comme l'a fait votre interlocuteur :

> Merci pour votre réponse.
>   Je vous remercie pour l'attention que vous m'avez porté.

Comment: lol encore vous! @Charly.

Comment: "Bonjour une nouvelle fois" me choque également... par contre, bonne idée "Merci pour votre réponse" :)

Comment: Well, it is quite exaggerated, but i bet you understood what i meant and why this should not appear in you mail ^^

Comment: @Random Pareil, mais ça me choque moins que "encore une fois", c'était la seule solution qui me passait par la tête pour transcrire le "bonjour, encore une fois". "Bonjour à nouveau" peut également le faire.

Comment: J'éviterais "Je vous remercie pour l'attention que vous m'avez porté". D'abord parce que c'est personnel (on porte attention à la demande, ou au message, mais pas directement à la personne, sauf si on l'a en face de soi). Et ensuite parce que j'ai tendance à réserver ça en fin de message, lorsque j'attends une action du lecteur. Du style : "Merci par avance à l'attention que vous porterez à ma demande..."

Answer (score 4):

As [Blue_Elephant](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/9932/blue-elephant), « encore une fois » is very odd. To mean the same thing, you would say "Re-bonjour", but it is familiar. So here, "Bonjour" is enough.

Also, « durant toute la journée » is odd, I think because of "durant", which seems to be used only for past events... so you should say "être disponible toute la journée".

Then, about "how to sell yourself", I think you shouldn't ever say that you are always available. That may mean you are doing nothing for the moment, which may be negative.
The person is giving you a precise date, so you don't have to say you are available the whole week. (s)he is asking you if you are ok for this date, so (s)he expect you to say "yes" and give an hour. So, in my opinion, you should say something like "Je suis disponible toute la journée, que pensez vous de 11h ?"

Comment: oh yes Very Interesting @Random. I wanted to throw fixing the date part on them. You are right better be sure of myself and just answer directly. no need beat around the bush

Answer (score 2):

I would state it this way

> Bonjour,
>   Je n'ai aucune contrainte pour la semaine du 18 juillet. Je peux prendre une journée du lundi au vendredi afin de procéder à l'entretien avec le consultant.
>   La date du 19 juillet me convient aussi. Je pourrai être disponible toute la journée.
>   Cordialement, xxxx,xxxx.

And you can maybe rephrase

> La date du 19 juillet me convient aussi. Je pourrai être disponible toute la journée.

Into (following [Random](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/7321/random) answer)

> Je suis aussi disponible le 19 juillet.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some comments about your updated/compiled reply:

- You have two variations of "merci" in the first line: "merci" and "je vous remercie". In plain good French, we avoid repetitions of words or variations of the same word.
- Month names are not capitalized in French. So you must write "19 juillet" and not "19 Juillet" (and also to be consistent with your "18 juillet").
- There's a debate about inserting the recipient name after "Bonjour Madame [Monsieur]". Most of the time, it is considered impolite to write "Bonjour Madame Martin" (or even worse: "Bonjour Mme. Martin"), and you should write "Bonjour Madame"/"Bonjour Monsieur"; it is not very known in France (most emails I receive starts with "Bonjour Monsieur *Evariste*" [EDIT: I've finally found a [reference for this rule](http://latlntic.unige.ch/grammaticalite/?page_id=1851)!]) but my own opinion is that you should avoid this formula. So, stay with "Bonjour Monsieur"/"Bonjour Madame" or "Bonjour" alone if you want it less formal (or if you don't know the gender of your contact).
  Unless I know the recipient and I call her/him by the first name, I personnaly stay with "Bonjour" alone (even if I know some consider "Bonjour" alone a little bit dry), and I use "Bonjour Pierre" for familiar conversations.
  If I wanted a very formal email, I'd go with "Chère Madame"/"Cher Monsieur" (meaning you need to know the gender!)
  Note: I've just noticed your contact is a "she" since she wrote "désolé**e**.
- You're missing a hyphen between "pensez" and "vous".
- If I want to write a very polite email, I generally avoid direct questions in it. So, I'd go with "par exemple à 10h" instead of "que pensez-vous de 10h ?". You may add "si cela vous convient aussi" in order to subtly ask a question!
- No dot after your signature.

Thus, here's my own version:

> Bonjour *[or "Bonjour Madame" or "Chère Madame"]*,
>
> Je vous remercie pour votre réponse et l'attention que vous m'avez portée.
>
> Je suis disponible la semaine du 18 juillet.
>
> La date du 19 juillet me convient également. Je suis disponible toute
>   la journée, par exemple à 10h, si cela vous convient aussi.
>
> Cordialement,
>
> Hani Xxx

Note: there's very few chances your contact even notices these improvments, unless he/she is very demanding about syntax and French language. In my own experience, this is less than 5% of email users! Considering the first email you got from your contact (it's not *that* meticulous!), I'm now 99% sure these improvments won't be noticed, but still).